# child window alignment center when main window minimize or maximise in wpf

Tags: wpf

I have main window in that we have child window, when i open the child window it is opening, and i alignment also proper, when i am minimize the window it is not in center align, we need child window should be center when minimize or maximize the main window.

Here is my code

```
<xctk:ChildWindow Name="loginchildwindow" WindowBorderBrush="Transparent" WindowBorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" WindowBackground="Transparent" Background="Transparent" OverlayBrush="{StaticResource LoginChildwindowBackgroundColor}" OverlayOpacity="50" CloseButtonVisibility="Collapsed"
WindowThickness="0" Caption="" WindowStartupLocation="Center" MinHeight="370" MinWidth="400" IsModal="True" />
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. Do you want your child window to change position after it is opened and then the parent is minimized/maximized or are you saying that when the parent is maximized and the child is then opened, it is not centered correctly?

Comment: Actually when i open child window when mainwindow is maximized it is centered correctly.But when i change the mainwindow height and width (i.e., restoring) child window is not centered.

Comment: Shouldn't WindowStartupLocation = CenterOwner ? I don't know that Center is in the enumeration

Comment: You could also look at this answer, I think it gives you a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452854/wpf-windowstartuplocation-centerowner-not-really-center-and-pops-all-over-wh