# how WindowStartupLocation works with many windows

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a lot of windows and every time I open new window I want the position to be the same as the previous window.

I tried this in every window :

`WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"`

But it didn't work: the window still pops up somewhere else.

I tried to set the owner in one of my window but this is still not working. I also tried the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452854/wpf-windowstartuplocation-centerowner-not-really-center-and-pops-all-over-wh) question but still no joy.

How can I ensure that every time I open new window (after previous window is closed) that I get the same position as the previous window?

Comment: New window of the same application or any app? I personally prefer `CenterScreen`.

Comment: @i486 same application, yes but i need it to following the previous window so if the user move the window to top right, the new window should be on top right also.

Comment: @i486 i mean it can be any window, not the same application

Comment: If you want a window to open in a specific location then you *must* use WindowStartupLocation.Manual and set the Left and Top properties.  It is entirely up to you to figure out what Left and Top need to be, "previous window" is too vague.  If it is an existing window, previously opened, then you need a reference to that window.  If it is a previously opened window but now closed then you need a variable.

Comment: In other words - you have to save new position after each move of window (e.g. in Registry / HKCU) and then restore last position at startup.

Comment: @HansPassant yes thanks, but the problem is that i have so many windows and it gonna take a very long time to have a variable for every windows i have

Comment: @i486 so in other words, i have to create variable for every windows right?

Comment: @Mirza You have to implement "manually" save-window-position feature. Then you may use it for many windows with copy-paste of `.cs` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set your windows default position in XAML(in every window file) like:

```
<Window x:Class="TabControl.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabControl"
    Title="MainWindow"    Height="300"          
    Top="100"
    Left="100"
```

or **as in your case** you can get the parent window's properties and set that to child window in code behind.(as you want to open at the position of parent window)

```
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var activeWindow = System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().FirstOrDefault(win=>win.IsActive);
        if(activeWindow != null)
        {
            this.Top = activeWindow.Top;
            this.Left = activeWindow.Left;
        }
    }
```

In place of `this.Parent` you can replace the parent window object. Hopefully Size of window is not your concern.

Comment: so i just put the top and left in every window? i dont need to use the `WindowStartupLocation`? i'll try it when i get home, thanks

Comment: @Mirza when you set left or Top that means you are using WindowStartupLocation=Manual automatically. You can also create a Window Opening Service to open your windows that way you don't have to write this code in every window.(if windows in your application is derived from a generic type window(your custom type) that will do this too)

Comment: i'm sorry for the late reply, the parent is null because i think i have to set it first? how can i set the previous windows as Parent?

Comment: the parent can be different here, i can go to B from A or C. so how can i have a dynamic parent like that

Comment: @Mirza please see my u[dated answer. you can place that code in Window.Activated event.

Comment: actually i already got the answer by manually set the posisiton in every window. but thank you for answering :)

Comment: @Mirza yeah! that is what I'm saying. you have to put it in every window. And the key point was to identify last window's position. did you do that by any other way?

Comment: @Mirza and your welcome. Feel free to accept the answer. :)