# WPF form is cradling the upper left hand corner of a remote desktop connection screen even though I specify "CenterScreen"

Tags: c#, wpf, remote-desktop

So I am having a form placement issue when launching a remote desktop connection session that automatically executes an application that is used as a main application portal.

I created this WPF form using C# and the Prism MVVM framework for accessing the company's billing desktop applications a user has permissions to.

So instead of distributing this main application and the billing applications on each user's desktop, the infrastructure team created a remote desktop connection file (*.rdp) that will be distributed to all users that have permissions to these billing desktop applications.

The remote desktop connection file has been modified where the user will login to the application server and ONLY be able to launch the application main portal and the billing applications they have permission to.

Here is the script for the RDP file

```
use multimon:i:0
desktopwidth:i:1920
desktopheight:i:1200
session bpp:i:32
winposstr:s:0,1,-1674,83,-248,1127
compression:i:1
keyboardhook:i:2
audiocapturemode:i:0
videoplaybackmode:i:1
connection type:i:7
networkautodetect:i:1
bandwidthautodetect:i:1
displayconnectionbar:i:1
enableworkspacereconnect:i:0
disable wallpaper:i:0
allow font smoothing:i:0
allow desktop composition:i:0
disable full window drag:i:1
disable menu anims:i:1
disable themes:i:0
disable cursor setting:i:0
bitmapcachepersistenable:i:1
full address:s:prod.goctii.com
audiomode:i:0
redirectprinters:i:1
redirectcomports:i:0
redirectsmartcards:i:1
redirectclipboard:i:1
redirectposdevices:i:0
autoreconnection enabled:i:1
authentication level:i:2
prompt for credentials:i:0
negotiate security layer:i:1
remoteapplicationmode:i:0
alternate shell:s:
shell working directory:s:
gatewayhostname:s:
gatewayusagemethod:i:4
gatewaycredentialssource:i:4
gatewayprofileusagemethod:i:0
promptcredentialonce:i:0
gatewaybrokeringtype:i:0
use redirection server name:i:0
rdgiskdcproxy:i:0
kdcproxyname:s:
alternate shell:s:"C:\CTII\AppMan\AppMan.exe"
```

So originally I had the **WindowStartupLocation = CenterScreen** in the XAML.

I would double click the remote desktop connection file that I placed on my desktop and then login with my credentials.

The main application portal form is displayed in the upper left hand corner of the remote desktop connection screen fully maximized as seen below

[image]

Now if I launch the FBM application from this application list and then click the button to return to the main application portal, the form is centered in the remote desktop connection window like it should as shown below.

[image]

So I placed the **WindowsStartupLocation = CenterScreen** in the constructor and removed it from the XAML with no success.

So I was looking through the StackOverflow community and found this article:  [Why does WindowStartupLocation = CenterScreen place my window somewhere other than the center of the screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185652/why-does-windowstartuplocation-centerscreen-place-my-window-somewhere-other-th)

I tried the **Edit #4 - Workaround** by creating a blank window that is launched first and then is hidden after the form has been displayed.  When it is closed, then the blank window is also closed.

It also didn't work.

So I am trying to figure out where is the needle in the haystack.

If anyone has any insight on what I can try, please post a URL or reply back with suggestions.

Thank you very much StackOverflow community for taking the time to review my case and provide feedback.

Comment: This sounds to me like a scenario for a RemoteApp instead of an RDP session with an alternate shell.

Comment: @Steeeve My colleague on the infrastructure team is going forward with using RemoteApp instead of an RDP with an alternate shell.  Thank you for your input.

Comment: @Steeeve  That did the trick.  Thank you.